# таблицы MySQL с двумя нижмними подчёркиваниями не переименовываются

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

Помогите понять странность поведения MySQL и php.

Есть БД с таблицами, большая часть которых имеет префикс `a1_`, то есть примерно так:

```
a1_table_users
a1_table_tasks
a1_table_lessons
```

Кроме этого в БД есть таблицы с удвоенным нижними подчёркиванием «`__`» в начале имени перед префиксом `__a1`, прим:

```
__a1_info
__a1_articles
```

Мне необходимо с помощью SQL запроса переименовать некоторые таблицы выборочно. Проблема в том, что если запрос выполняется на переименовывание таблицы с двойным подчёркиванием в начале имени, то ничего не происходит.

Вот такой код работает и переименовывает таблицы

```sql
RENAME TABLE `a1_articles` TO `b2_articles`;
RENAME TABLE `a1_subscrib` TO `b2_subscrib`;
 ...etc > work
```

Запрос отрпавляется инструкцией в php-скрипте:

```php
$mysqli->query('RENAME TABLE `a1_articles` TO `b2_articles`;');
```

Но по какой-то причине для таблиц с двойным подчёркиванием (`__`) в начале имени запросы не выполняются и таблицы не переименовываются:

```sql
RENAME TABLE `__a1_table` TO `__b2_table`;
RENAME TABLE `__a1_users` TO `b2_users`;
 ...etc > don't work
```

При этом я могу зайти в PhpMyAdmin и выполнить команду

```sql
`RENAME TABLE `__a1_user` TO `b2_users`;
```

в консоли, и запрос будет выполнен, таблица будет переименована.

Также через PMA я могу вручную переименовывать в таблицы с именами содержащими двойное подчёркивание в начале имени, и обратно.

Подскажите, в чём причина такого поведения MySQL или PHP?

Comment: MySQL 14.14 - все работает отлично. Какая версия? Строка RENAME TABLE `__a1_table` TO `__a1_table` имена совпадают - не в этом проблема?

Comment: прошу прощения, опечатка исправлена, на самом деле ``…__a1_table` TO `__b2_table`…`` . Версия MySQL 5.6.39. Загадка в том, что из PhpMyAdmin, который установлен на том же сервере, команды выполняются. Однако если разместить скрипт в другом виртуальном хосте и сделать вышеприведённый запрос через ``$mysqli->query('RENAME TABLE `__a1_articles` TO `b2_articles`;'); `` то все таблицы, которые содержат в начале имени `__` остаются без изменений

Comment: что говорит `print(mysqli_error($mysqli))` после запроса?

Comment: `var_dump(  mysqli_error( $myqli )  )` возвращает пустую строку. В итоге по косточкам разобрал проект.. проблема решена.. спасибо участникам темы, что наводящими вопросами довели до верного результата ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема возникла из-за невнимательности. Объект встроенного класса $MYSQLI инициализировался в свойство пользовательского класса разрабатываемого проекта, который предназначен для `include` в рабочие скрипты. В процессе работы программы была подключена сторонняя библиотека, которая по-умолчанию расширяла одноимённый класс `db`.

В результате чего наложились методы(функции) друг на друга. В сторонней библиотеке есть всякие натыканные пасхалки и плюшки, например: обработка плейсхолдеров и экспресс-замена спец.комбинаций символов на выражения. Это и привело к странному поведению php-приложения.